# Loaad a openCV Haarcascade from QT ressources

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to add the openCV cascades to the ressource managment of QT. But i'm failed.

I've  tested this code:

```c++
// load cascades
QUrl *location_cascade= new QUrl("qrc:/cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
std::string file=location_cascade->toString().toStdString();
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( file);
```

But than the compiler said:

```
cannot convert 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'void* cvLoad(const char*, CvMemStorage*, const char*, const char**)'
```

Has someone an idea?

**Update**
Currently the file is in the source folder of the project. Can i access this file by relative path? maybe by a constant that points to the src.dir?

greetings

Comment: Have you looked at openBR which uses qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler tells you that first argument of `cvLoad` should be `const char*`, but you are passing `std::string`. You need to call it like `cvLoad(file.c_str())`.

But even if you manage to compile that code it will probably not work, as openCV knows nothing about Qt resources and won't be able to open the file with that name.

Comment: okay, thank you. Is there another way to get access to a relative path like the src. dir? (I've updated my question)

Comment: You can use `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` to get the directory that contains the executable. I think this is more "portable" than binding to sources dir.

Answer (score 1):

Even so, this question is 2 years old, I want to share the workaround I used.

```
QString sPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/frontalface.xml")
QFile::copy(":/android-sources/OpenCV/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml" , sPath);
cv::CascadeClassifier faceCascade = cv::CascadeClassifier(sPath.toStdString());
QFile::remove(sPath);
```

It works, but you have to go the detour over the local harddrive. Still usefull for android applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace cv;    
QFile xmlRes(":/new/cascades/res/cascade.xml");
    if (xmlRes.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QString data(xmlRes.readAll());
        FileStorage fs(data.toStdString().c_str(), FileStorage::MEMORY | FileStorage::FORMAT_XML);
        if (!cascade.read(fs["cascade"]))
            qDebug() << "ERROR: Could not read classifier cascade.";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.